# Dialog showModal() does not work

Tags: javascript, safari

Why does this code not work in Safari?

```
var dialog_=document.createElement("dialog");
dialog_.id="dialog";
$("body").append(dialog_);
...
document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();
```

[showModal()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_dialog_showmodal.asp) function should work in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

In a first answer to this question I stated that the method has been deprecated, what it is wrong: `showModalDialog()` (a different thing) has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog).

Thanks to *cregox* (see comments) for reporting it.

---

The [HTMLDialogElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) interface is an experimental technology that, so far, has not been implemented by Safari.

If you don't know *caniuse.com* (much more reliable than *w3schools.com*), it will be a huge help for you in the future: check [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog).

I have reported the mistake to *w3schools*.

Comment: it's not deprecated, it's experimental. you've got the wrong MDN reference there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal